# Apply a shake transition to a single position from array[i] on mouse hovering

Tags: typescript, frontend, vuejs3

I'm trying to apply is a shake transition when the mouse is hovering the v-card, I reach the point to shake the whole array but I do not know how to acces the position so i can apply this shake to a single position from the array here's my code (something like @mouseover="hoverShanking in optionsTest[index]"), any idea how can I get there?:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard.vue'
import type { IOption } from '../interfaces/IOption'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{}>()
const emits = defineEmits<{}>()

const notificaciones = ref(14)
const prueba = ref(
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis numquam, dicta corrupti harum aliquid doloremque dignissimos. Provident ab sed consequatur commodi, aspernatur adipisci dolor veritatis rerum quidem nulla dolore nemo'
)

const optionsTest: IOption[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'GitLab',
    desc: 'Plataforma para control de versiones',
    url: 'https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in',
    icono: 'http://localhost:5173/src/assets/gitlab.png',
    noti: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'GL',
    desc: 'Descripcion de la opcion 2',
    url: '',
    icono: '',
    noti: 0
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Swagger',
    desc: `Estructuración de API's`,
    url: 'https://swagger.io/',
    icono: 'http://localhost:5173/src/assets/swagger.png',
    noti: 0
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: `Cola de Email's`,
    desc: 'Emails',
    url: '',
    icono: 'http://localhost:5173/src/assets/email.png',
    noti: 0
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Cola de Documentos',
    desc: 'Documentos',
    url: '',
    icono: 'http://localhost:5173/src/assets/documentos2.png',
    noti: 0
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'W2P',
    desc: 'Web to project',
    url: 'https://call.tpaas.es/?lang=es-ES',
    icono: '',
    noti: 0
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Reservas',
    desc: 'Reservas',
    url: '',
    icono: '',
    noti: 0
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Servicios BBDD',
    desc: 'Bases de datos',
    url: '',
    icono: 'http://localhost:5173/src/assets/BBDD.png',
    noti: 0
  }
]

const hoverOption = ref()
const shaking = ref(true)

function hoverShaking(): void {
  shaking.value = true
  setTimeout(() => {
    shaking.value = false
  }, 750)
  console.log(shaking.value)
}
//@mouseover="hoverShaking"

//@mouseover="hoverOption = index"
//@mouseleave="hoverOption = undefined"
</script>

<template>
  <v-container class="container" :fluid="true">
    <v-row no-gutters justify="center">
      <v-col cols="auto" v-for="(item, index) in optionsTest" :class="{ 'apply-shake': shaking }">
        <Dashboard
          :item="item"
          :notificaciones="notificaciones"
          :key="index"
          @mouseover="hoverShaking"
        ></Dashboard>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<style>
.cardOption {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #2a5e92;
  color: white;
}
.hover-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.prueba {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
.apply-shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.bounce:hover {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}
</style>
 }        

    40%,        
    60% {        

      transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);        
      }        
      }        

      .apply-shake {        
animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;        
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);        

         }    
      .bounce:hover {           
      animation-name: bounce;      
      animation-timing-function: ease;        
      }        
      </style>
```

Comment: is this really your code, did it pass the review

Comment: I pasted it and it gets unformatted, is that what you mean?

Comment: You're closing `</style>` twice, which leaves some of your CSS out. Most likely, that's why it doesn't apply. You might want to start using an IDE, as it highlights these types of errors. If you're already using one, start paying attention to the red underlines in your code and solve them, one by one, based on the IDE's hints. If you use an IDE and you don't see red stuff for the above code, get someone more experienced to set up `eslint` + `prettier` in your project and then pull and run `eslint --ext ts,tsx,js,jsx,json,md,vue --fix` in project root folder.